# How should one deploy graphic bevel buttons in GMS3?

Tags: dialog, dpi, dm-script

This may end up simply becoming a bug report, but since I found a workaround for a similar problem with dialog graphics in GMS3, I'm hoping there may be a way to get bevel buttons to display correctly also. The following example script demonstrates the issue:

```
    class ModelessDialogWithBevelButton : UIFrame
    {
        Object Init(Object self)
        {
            TagGroup dialogSpec = DLGCreateDialog("");
            TagGroup dialogItems = dialogSpec.DLGGetItems();

            Number size = 100;
            Number factor = 4 * Pi() / size;
            Image graphicImage := RGBImage("Graphic", 4, size, size);
            graphicImage = RGB(255 * Sin(factor * iradius) ** 2, 255 * Cos(factor * iradius) ** 2, 0);

            // Add labeled box with graphic
            Number scaler = 1;
            TagGroup graphicBoxSpec = DLGCreateBox("Graphic");
            TagGroup graphicBoxItems = graphicBoxSpec.DLGGetItems();
            TagGroup graphicSpec = DLGCreateGraphic(scaler * size, scaler * size);
            graphicSpec.DLGAddBitMap(graphicImage);
            graphicBoxItems.DLGAddElement(graphicSpec);
            dialogItems.DLGAddElement(graphicBoxSpec, "Left", "West");

            // Add labeled box with bevel button
            TagGroup buttonBoxSpec = DLGCreateBox("Bevel Button");
            TagGroup buttonBoxItems = buttonBoxSpec.DLGGetItems();
            TagGroup buttonSpec = DLGCreateBevelButton(graphicImage, graphicImage, "DoButton");
            buttonBoxItems.DLGAddElement(buttonSpec);
            dialogItems.DLGAddElement(buttonBoxSpec, "Left", "West");

            return self.super.Init(dialogSpec);
        }

        void DoButton(Object self)
        {
            OKDialog("Button clicked");
        }
    }

    void main()
    {
        Object dialog = Alloc(ModelessDialogWithBevelButton).Init();
        dialog.Display("Bevel Button Test");
    }

    main();
```

While the bitmap of the graphic element only fills the top-left quarter of the specified graphic area, the bevel button bitmap ends up filling only the central quarter of the bevel button area. In the case of the graphic, we can workaround this mismatch by setting the scaler variable to 0.5 (at least in GMS 3.4 running under the latest Win10). However, I have not found any way to scale down the bevel button graphic area to match its bitmap. Has anyone else run into this and found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a different manifestation of the same issue as

**[Has deployment of dialog graphics changed in GMS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61036091/1302888)**

However, as far as fixing is concerned, you can use the command `DLGExternalPadding` with negative values to "shrink" the bevel button. This solution, however, is as volatile with respect to dpi settings of Windows10 as others are.